# How to text zoom-in and zoom-out using FFMPEG command?

Tags: video, text, zooming, android-ffmpeg

I want to set text with zoom-in and zoom-out filter on video using FFMPEG command.

```
"-i", inputPath, "-filter_complex", \
    "[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/project/abc.ttf: \
     text='Hello!!':fontsize=50:fontcolor=ec1818:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:\
     boxborderw=5:shadowcolor=white:shadowx=5:shadowy=5, \
     zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(on,42),10),zoom+0.0200,zoom-0.0065)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom)/2': \
     y='ih/2-(ih/zoom)/2':d=500", "-c:a", "copy", "-preset", "ultrafast", outPutPath
```

I used the above command (written in one line) but it not display anything, So what can I do?
Please help me.
Thank you in advance.